# How should I design the stored proc and c # method to get such results

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem here.

In c# code I am constructing a method called 
`saveImages(Guid ImageId, String url, byte[] imageData)` which calls a stored procedure to store the data on a sql server.

I understand all the process of how to construct a stored procedure and call it from c# code.

My question is, now I want the code to behave in such a way that if save successfully return the imageId otherwise return null.

How should I construct the stored procedure? How do I set the parameters?
And how do I get the returned value in C#?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you reach so far, show us.

Comment: what might be a good idea is if you place the calling of the stored procedure in a try catch block that way if the insert statement fails it will be caught and you can deal with the error by returning a null, if no error happens return the value that was gotten from the stored procedure by adding ;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); to the end of your insert statement in the stored procedure

Comment: I noticed two of your previous questions were closed and this is about to be as well. When asking questions, [please take the time to explain what you have tried](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) using a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://www.sscce.org/). You say you "understand everything", but you have not provided anything and ask a very broad questions; "How should I construct the stored procedure". If you have not tried anything, instead tell us why not and what you have searched for and are having problems with. Did you search for "stored procedure parameters c#" for instance?

Comment: Sorry for the late follow-up. I was engaged with something else lately. Very good tips by you guys and I will try to improve my question skills. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you start by adding:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

at the end of your Stored Procedure.

Your method should look something like:

```
public int saveImages(Guid ImageId, String url, byte[] imageData)
    {
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand() {
        Connection = your connection,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        CommandText = "your Stored Procedure"
      })
      {
        try
        {
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue(...); // Add your Parameters here
          return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch
        {
          return 0;
        }
      }
    }
```